# When/how/where is parent.frame in a default argument interpreted?

Tags: r, environment

Truth be told, I'm just being lazy here, but perhaps someone could someday profit from the answer being here.

Say I define a function like:

```
fn<-function(envir=parent.frame())
{
    #do something with envir
}
```

My question is: what might I expect to be the content of envir?

Context: I had a rather long function f1 that contained a call to parent.frame. Now, I want to extract part of that function (containing the parent.frame call) into a new helper function f2 (which will then be called by f1), and I want to be sure that f1 does the same as it did before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated [within the evaluation frame of the function call](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation), from which place `parent.frame()` is the calling environment. `envir`'s value will thus be a pointer to the environment from which `fn` was called.

Also, just try it out to see for yourself:

```
debug(fn)
fn()
# debugging in: fn()
# debug at #2: {
# }
Browse[2]> envir
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't think evaluation frame is well defined - I think local environment is more clear.

Comment: @hadley -- Nice suggestion, thanks. In the future, I'll probably go with either that or "environment of the current evaluation".

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting. So that means that in this case, there would be quite a difference between calling $fn(parent.frame())$ and $fn()$, right?

Comment: @NickSabbe -- Yes, exactly! `fn <- function(envir=parent.frame()) print(envir); g <- function() fn(); h <- function() f(parent.frame()); g(); h()`.