# Strange behavior in default argument enclos =parent.frame() of eval function

Tags: r, expression-evaluation

I'm currently having some issues understanding the behavior of the eval function- specifically the enclos/third argument when an argument isn't supplied to it/ the default argument parent.fame() is used.

```
name <- function(x){
    print(substitute(x))
    t <- substitute(x)
    eval(t, list(a=7), parent.frame())
}
z <-5
name(a+z)
# returns 12, makes sense because this amounts to
# eval(a+z, list(a=7), glovalenv())


# however the return here makes no sense to me

  name2 <- function(x){
    print(substitute(x))
    t <- substitute(x)
    eval(t, list(a=7)) # third/enclosure argument is left missing
}

z <-5
name2(a+z)
# Also returns 12
```

I'm having trouble understanding why the second call returns 12. According to my understanding of R, the second call should result in an error because

1) eval's default third argument enclos= parent.frame(), which is not specified.

2) Therefore, parent.frame() is evaluated in the local environment of eval. This is confirmed by Hadley in [When/how/where is parent.frame in a default argument interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504960/when-how-where-is-parent-frame-in-a-default-argument-interpreted)

3) Thus, the last expression ought to resolve to eval(a+z, list(a=7), executing environment of name)

4) This should return an error because z is not defined in the executing environment of name nor in list(a=7).

Can someone please explain what's wrong with this logic?

Comment: the calling environment of name is the global environment in this case, but in general you'd be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z` will be available inside the function since it's defined in .GlobalEnv.

Simply put,

```
name <- function(x) {
  print(z)
}
z <- 5

name(z)

# [1] 5
```

So while `a` is still unknown until `eval(t, list(a=7))`, `z` is already available. If `z` is not defined inside `name`, it will be looked for in .GlobalEnv. What might be counterintuitive is that `(a+z)` is undefined unless you specify an environment for `a`. But for `z`, there is no need to do so.

Comment: This is due to lexical scoping. Got it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, you nailed it: lexical scoping. :)