# R eval has misleading documentation for the case that the envir argument is list or pairlist

Tags: r, eval, metaprogramming

I am not sure if this should be posted on [R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel) (if so, just let me know...) but there seems to be at least a mistake in the documentation of R's `eval()` function, which is essential for R's Non Standard evaluation features, or what am I getting wrong?

```
> eval   
function (expr, envir = parent.frame(), enclos = if (is.list(envir) || 
    is.pairlist(envir)) parent.frame() else baseenv()) 
.Internal(eval(expr, envir, enclos))
<bytecode: 0x0000000009534280>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

This and also this part of `eval`'s help on the `enclos` argument

```
> Relevant when envir is a (pair)list or a data frame. Specifies the
enclosure, i.e., where R looks for objects not found in envir. This can be
NULL (interpreted as the base package environment, baseenv()) or an
environment.
```

indicates that whenever a list is supplied to `eval()`'s `envir` argument, the value of `enclos` is (lazily) evaluated to `parent.frame()`, so it should be the same as supplying `parent.frame()` additionally (but this time directly). However, note that the following two code chunks where I only change this, don't return the same.

```
> rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
> f1 <- function(){
   y <- 2
   f2 <- function(){
     eval(quote(y), envir = list())
   }
   f2
 }
> f3 <- f1()
> f3()
[1] 2
```

and

```
> rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
> f1 <- function(){
   y <- 2
   f2 <- function(){
     eval(quote(y), envir = list(),
          enclos = parent.frame())
   }
   f2
 }
> f3 <- f1()
> f3()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
```

So the only conclusion I can get from here is that it seems, that for data frames and lists the enclosing environment per default is not the `parent.env()`. Instead it seems that R is looking in the current execution environment. Here the only relevant part that I can find in `?eval` on that:

```
> When evaluating expressions in a data frame that has been passed as an
argument to a function, the relevant enclosure is often the caller's 
environment, i.e., one needs eval(x, data, parent.frame()).
```

Which somehow indicates, that one should set `parent.frame()` explicitly. And that the indicated behaviour above is indeed not what `eval()` does by default...(at least for the case, when `envir` is set to a list/pairlist).

For me this is very confusing. However, I am not sure if I get something wrong and would appreciate any answer or comment on that.

Comment: I guess the difference between those two is in what is captured as `parent.frame()` --  passing "enclos" explicitly will evaluate the `parent.frame()` at the time `f3` is called (.GlobalEnv in the  first case; i.e. the parent of `f3`'s environment) while a `missing` "enclos" will evaluate to the parent of `eval`; i.e. the current running environment of `f3`. As a simple example note the difference between `fA()()` and `fB()()` from ...

Comment: ... `f0 = function(e) print(e); f1 = function(e = parent.frame()) f0(e); fA = function() function() { print(parent.frame()); print(environment()); f1() } ; fB = function() function() { print(parent.frame()); print(environment()); f1(parent.frame()) } `

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks a lot! This really helped. If you post this as an anwswer, I will mark it. It's also really interesting, that there is a general distinction between default and supplied arguments as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504960/when-how-where-is-parent-frame-in-a-default-argument-interpreted and here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific example, in the first case, the definition of `f3` is:

```
f3
#function(){
#     eval(quote(y), envir = list())
#   }
#<environment: 0x02a41584>
```

The default `enclos = parent.frame()` argument will be evaluated in the evaluation frame (i.e. "inside") of `eval` -- the parent of `eval`s current environment is the current `environment()` of its wrapper function (`f3`). And its wrapper function "remembers" where it was created and searches for the `y` correctly to find it.

In the second case, `f3` is defined as:

```
f3
#function(){
#     eval(quote(y), envir = list(),
#          enclos = parent.frame())
#   }
#<environment: 0x02a4e5e4>
```

Here, `enclos = parent.frame()` is evaluated in the evaluation `environment()` of `f3` and, upon calling `f3()`, its parent is the `.GlobalEnv` where there is no `y`.

As a clearer example (yet equally nested as the example) we could consider:

```
f0 = function(e) print(e)
f1 = function(e = parent.frame()) f0(e)
fA = function() #returns a function
{
    function() 
    { 
        print(parent.frame())
        print(environment())
        f1() 
    }
}   
fB = function() # returns a function
{
    function() 
    { 
        print(parent.frame())
        print(environment())
        f1(parent.frame()) 
    }
}
```

And call:

```
fA()()
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>  #<- parent of `fA()`'s `environment()`
#<environment: 0x06ff25bc>   #<- current env of `fA()`
#<environment: 0x06ff25bc>   #<- parent of `f1` == current of `fA()`

fB()()
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>  #<- parent of `fA()`'s `environment()`
#<environment: 0x06fec304>   #<- current env of `fA()`
#<environment: R_GlobalEnv>  #<- parent is `eval`ed as parent of `fA()`'s current
```

As Taz notes, the distinction between default and supplied arguments is stated in the [definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation) manual. Fooling a bit around we could see it in action by trying to reach the promises of arguments:

First, a helper function to access the promises of current arguments:

```
.ff = inline::cfunction(sig = c(symarg = "symbol", env = "environment", penv = "environment"), body = '
    SEXP arg = findVar(symarg, env), ans = allocVector(VECSXP, 5);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, 0, PRCODE(arg)); 
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, 1, PRENV(arg));
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, 2, eval(PRCODE(arg), PRENV(arg)));
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, 3, env);
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, 4, penv);
    return(ans);
')
```

And the function whose arguments we 'll track:

```
ff = function(arg = parent.frame())
{
    ans = setNames(.ff(quote(arg), environment(), parent.frame()), 
                   c("expr", "envir", "val", "cur", "par"))

    cat(sprintf("promise:\n\tcall: '%s'\n\tsearched at: '%s'\n\tfound as: '%s'\ncurrent: '%s'\nparent: '%s'\n%s\n", 
                deparse(ans$expr), capture.output(ans$envir), 
                capture.output(ans$val), capture.output(ans$cur),
                capture.output(ans$par), strrep("-", 40)))

    return(invisible(ans))
}
```

And a simple example:

```
ff()
#promise:
#        call: 'parent.frame()'
#        searched at: '<environment: 0x06fff594>'
#        found as: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#current: '<environment: 0x06fff594>'
#parent: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#----------------------------------------

ff(parent.frame())
#promise:
#        call: 'parent.frame()'
#        searched at: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#        found as: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#current: '<environment: 0x06fcce20>'
#parent: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#----------------------------------------
```

Or a more nested case:

```
fnest1 = function() ff()
fnest2 = function() ff(parent.frame())

fnest1()
#promise:
#        call: 'parent.frame()'
#        searched at: '<environment: 0x028d1ccc>'
#        found as: '<environment: 0x028d1d20>'
#current: '<environment: 0x028d1ccc>'
#parent: '<environment: 0x028d1d20>'
#----------------------------------------

fnest2()
#promise:
#        call: 'parent.frame()'
#        searched at: '<environment: 0x026866b8>'
#        found as: '<environment: R_GlobalEnv>'
#current: '<environment: 0x0268662c>'
#parent: '<environment: 0x026866b8>'
#----------------------------------------
```